# Rhythmbox Extract Speed

Tags: rhythmbox, cd, extract, cd-ripping

How can you specify the extract speed in Rhythmbox 3.1? I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 64bit and Rhythmbox's extract speed is really slow ripping a music CD. How do you speed that up?

Thanks